# Get-ADForest - Could not find a forest identified by: "xxxx"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Here's the command I run:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential # Feed in credentials for some.domain.com
Get-ADForest -Server some.domain.com -Credential $Credentials
```

And it reports:

```
Get-ADForest : Could not find a forest identified by: 'some.domain.com'
```

I've tried all kinds of different things for the `-Server` parameter, including using the `hostname.domain.name.com` and nothing works. Is it possible it is being blocked?

However, if I run a:

```
Get-ADUser username -Server 'some.domain.com' -Credential $Credentials
```

It returns the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to go through the documentation for [`Get-ADForest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adforest?view=winserver2012-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2012r2-ps) to understand what might be happening in your case:

> The ***Get-ADForest*** cmdlet gets the Active Directory forest specified by
>   the parameters. You can specify the forest by setting the Identity or
>   Current parameters..........
>
> To retrieve the forest of the local computer or current logged on user
>   (CLU), set the Current parameter to LocalComputer or LoggedOnUser. When
>   you set the Current parameter, you do not need to set the Identity
>   parameter.......
>
> When the Current parameter is set to LocalComputer or LoggedOnUser,
>   the cmdlet uses the Server and Credential parameter values to
>   determine the domain and the credentials to use to identify the domain
>   of the forest according to the following rules......
>
> -- If the Server and Credential parameters are specified:
>
> The domain is set to the domain of the specified server and the cmdlet
>   checks to make sure that the server is in the domain of the
>   LocalComputer or LoggedOnUser. Then the credentials specified by the
>   Credential parameter are used to get the domain. **An error is
>   returned when the server is not in the domain of the LocalComputer or
>   LoggedOnUser.**

---

I believe the error which you're receiving is because the last line is not being satisfied. Please verify the same in your case because it seems the server which you're specifying is either not in the domain of the LocalComputer or the LoggedOnUser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the two examples you mention, are two different CMDlets. Let's not confuse the two of them.

About Get-ADForest:
Judging upon the information from this fact sheet about [Get-ADForest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adforest?view=win10-ps)

Would it help you to use -Identity "some.domain.com" instead? From what i can gather, either you use the -Identity switch(which is mandatory), or you pipe an object to the CMDlet.

The Identity switch takes these values:

- A fully qualified domain
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A DNS host name
- A NetBIOS name

Test:

```
    Get-ADForest -Identity 'some.domain.com' -Credential $Credentials
```

Comment: I believe that Martin is on the right path. The `-Identity` parameter indicates what forest you are trying to gather information *about*, and the `-Server` parameter indicates what server you want to gather that information *from*.